# How to populate $_SERVER['Remote_User'] variable with PHP running as CGI?

Tags: php, windows, cgi

I am trying in vain to get the variable `$_SERVER['Remote_User']` to authenticate users of my inhouse-app.

Is there any way to do this with PHP running as CGI?

I have tried all the workarrounds that i found while googeling (rewrite-rules that sets the variable in .htaccess and then explodes a b64 encoded string).

Or is there some other genious way to get the user-name of the person visiting my site?

Here is a print-out of my $_SERVER array:

```
Array
(
[HTTP_HOST] => tnxp.telenor.net
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-us,en;q=0.5
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
[HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
[PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at tnxp.telenor.net Port 80


[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
[SERVER_NAME] => tnxp.telenor.net
[SERVER_ADDR] => 10.179.98.20
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 148.121.183.28
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html
[SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/ew/index.php
[REMOTE_PORT] => 50315
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[REQUEST_URI] => /ew/
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /ew/index.php
[PHP_SELF] => /ew/index.php
[PHP_AUTH_USER] => t820082
[PHP_AUTH_PW] => asdf
[REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1359703708.68
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1359703708
)
```

Ideally i would like this to contain [REMOTE_USER] => *clients username*

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Browser can't send this variable!!! because its OS username that is not legal to send...

Comment: Akam Omer: I am not sure this is correct. I can fetch this with Active X in IE, and it works with php not running in CGI.

Answer (score 0):

[$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables are something you shouldn't set. They are set by server when script is loaded and will be reset on next load.

Use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) instead (there's also separate class for handling sessions in pure CGI if you need it - just google CGI Sessions - lots of documentation there).

Comment: I think i am missspelling the question. I know that it is set by the server when the script is loaded, but this is the problem -> the variable is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$loginName = substr($loginName, 0, 2).strToLower(substr($loginName, 2));



$authorizedUserList = Array();

$authorizedUserList[] = "user1";

$authorizedUserList[] = "user2";

$authorizedUserList[] = "user3";

$authorizedUserList[] = "user4";
forEach($authorizedUserList as $authorizedUser){

    if(strToUpper($authorizedUser) == strToUpper($loginName)){

        $authCheckPass = true;

    }

}
```